# Which fonts are similar to League Spartan?

Tags: font-recommendation

League Spartan is a font that I really use in my designs, but when doing presentations or pitching, I can't seem to find this font in Google Slides nor Google Docs. Any ideas of fonts that resemble League Spartan? Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: I don’t know much about Google Docs or Slides, but if you like League Spartan, you’ll want to know about Spartan MB (http://www.mtbailey.com/portfolio/spartan.html).

Comment: There's probably a lot of fonts similar to this one, YOU just have to search for it. "How similar" will depend on who is answering.

Answer (score 1):

Century Gothic **Bold**
It is its mother typeface. Almost the same but slight difference. 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Spartan is named for a 1930s typeface of that name which was a knock-off of Futura.

So Futura and any typeface with a similar design would be related, for example Monotype's Twentieth Century and Century Gothic, a 1980s redraw of it.

One thing to bear in mind is that different sizes of metal Futura had very different designs. Spartan seems to be based on smaller sizes of metal type: the design is quite bold and quite wide. Some digital fonts are based on the larger sizes of metal type of Futura, they have a more spindly design and the ascenders seem very high. The version of Futura included with Macs is like this. You'll want to think about if a font you pick works well at the point size you're planning to use it for.